# Amazon ECS error: cannot create a task definition with no containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have been following a tutorial regarding using docker compose with the AWS ECS service located [here](https://medium.com/@Electricste/amazon-ecs-using-the-cli-with-docker-compose-74287f19b181).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the installation of the ecs-cli was successful.
However, I have been receiving the following error when I try to run `sudo ecs-cli compose up` in the directory containing the docker-compose.yml file

> ERRO[0000] Unable to open ECS Compose Project            error="cannot create a task definition with no containers; invalid service config"
>
> FATA[0000] Unable to create and read ECS Compose Project 
>   error="cannot create a task definition with no containers; invalid
>   service config"

How are docker-compose.yml files and by extension multi-container docker applications supposed to be used with AWS ECS?

Comment: have similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found it was because of yml file formatting. If you did a straight copy and paste of the compose yml, it's missing the correct indentations. Fix those and it'll work.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: amazon/amazon-ecs-sample
    ports:
    - "80:80"
```